# Azure DEVOPS make pull request using on-behalf-of flow

Tags: azure-devops, oauth, azure-active-directory, microsoft-identity-platform, on-behalf-of

I am trying to figure out what is needed so that my application is able to make a pull request on behalf of my user.

I have an app registration, for this app registration I am requesting the following API permission:

`https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/user_impersonation`

Once the user accesses my REST API with a proper bearer token, I need to obtain the on-behalf token so that I may contact the Azure Devops APIs.

Question is what scopes do I need to request for the on-behalf-of token so that I may create pull requests as my authenticated user?

The git repo to which I'm trying to create the pull request is hosted on `o365exchange.visualstudio.com`.

Comment: If you are voting to close, your written feedback is also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

to create pull request on Azure DevOps Serivces side, you could call the rest api: [POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pullrequests?api-version=6.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-requests/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP)

You could find the needed scope under the doc:

[image]

You could find the corresponding scope details in the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fmarketplace-extensibility%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops#scopes):
[image]

When you register your app, you could choose it here:

[image]

I hope this could do some help. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. This seems to be what one needs to do in order to have a GUI app access the APIs using the accessCode flow but unfortunately I need to do the on-behalf-of flow. Your post is helpful however and I want to know where did you find the authorization and token urls?

Comment: Hi @Liviu, for my upper post authorization and token urls, you could find them in the doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-requests/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP. And for different rest api, you could navigate to the left search bar to check different rest api details include the authorization and token urls needed correspondily. Thanks.